# JSTL: iterate list but treat first element differently

Tags: java, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm trying to process a list using jstl.  I want to treat the first element of the list differently than the rest. Namely, I want only the first element to have display set to block, the rest should be hidden.

What I have seems bloated, and does not work.

Thanks for any help.

```
<c:forEach items="${learningEntry.samples}" var="sample">
    <!-- only the first element in the set is visible: -->
    <c:if test="${learningEntry.samples[0] == sample}">
        <table class="sampleEntry">
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${learningEntry.samples[0] != sample}">
        <table class="sampleEntry" style="display:hidden">
    </c:if>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It can be done even shorter, without `<c:if>`:

```
<c:forEach items="${learningEntry.samples}" var="sample" varStatus = "status">
    <table class="sampleEntry" ${status.first ? '' : 'style = "display:none"'}> 
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Based on use case you can also use a when statement inside the foreach loop `<c:when test="${status.first }"></c:when>`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, declare varStatus="stat" in the foreach element, so you can ask it if it's the first or the last. Its a variable of type LoopTagStatus.

This is the doc for LoopTagStatus:
http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html
It has more interesting properties...

```
<c:forEach items="${learningEntry.samples}" var="sample" varStatus="stat">
    <!-- only the first element in the set is visible: -->
    <c:if test="${stat.first}">
        <table class="sampleEntry">
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${!stat.first}">
        <table class="sampleEntry" style="display:none">
    </c:if>
```

**Edited: copied from axtavt**

It can be done even shorter, without `<c:if>`:

```
<c:forEach items="${learningEntry.samples}" var="sample" varStatus = "status">
    <table class="sampleEntry" ${status.first ? '' : 'style = "display:none"'}> 
</c:forEach>
```